# how to programmatically position an ImageView off-screen Android

Tags: java, android

I need to position an ImageView off-screen in order to animate it but I can't get it working. I need to support api 9+ and I tried the following code:

```
        ImageView camion = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.camion);

        int amountOffscreen = (int)(camion.getWidth() * 0.8); /* or whatever */
        boolean offscreen = true; /* true or false */


        int xOffset = (offscreen) ? amountOffscreen : 0;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams rlParams = 
            (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)camion.getLayoutParams();
        rlParams.setMargins(-1*xOffset, 0, xOffset, 0);
        camion.setLayoutParams(rlParams);
```

But the ImageView frame remains the same.

Comment: You tried using xml animations?

Comment: No never tried it, for the animation I was thinking about using a TranslateAnimation. Do you have any example of an animation created in xml?

Comment: Maybe you could have a look at http://nineoldandroids.com/ - it's a backport of the Animation API that so it works on Android 1.+ and up... On a side note: by supporting Api level 9 you're basically limiting yourself a lot and Api level 10 and below accounts for roughly 5% of the user base. You should definitely look into moving your minSdkTarget up...